# Adding to end of custom Linked List throws a NPE on "newNode.data = .."

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, linked-list

Hi can anyone help me out with a LinkedList issue I am having. I am trying to add a node storing OBJ to the end of my list, but I cannot seem to get why its not working. Below is the code I have so far:

```
public void addLast(int obj)
{
    ListNode newNode = new ListNode();
    newNode=head;
        while(newNode!=null)
        {
            newNode=newNode.link;
        }
        if(newNode==null)
        {
            newNode.data=obj;
        }
```

I can paste the whole code if needed but this is just the section that I cannot get to work right.
Currently there is about 5 nodes containing data from OBJ so I am traversing the link with a while loop and then I reach the end I insert newNode containing OBJ

The current code throws an null point exception error in this part: `newNode.data=obj;`.

Why isn't it working?  Appreciate any help, Thanks!

Comment: How are you going to do newNode.data if newNode is null?

Comment: If `newNode==null` is `true` then you try to access the node's data.  Since the node is null there isn't any data to access so you get the exception.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help, i now realise i needed another node to hold OBJ and then traverse and finally point the last node to the node containing OBJ. Thanks! really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if you use your head Node to begin with you don't need to create a node before that. Secondly while you are iterating over your structure you are jumping one step too far.

```
public void addLast(int obj)
{
    if (head == null) {
        // If we add an element for the first time
        head = new ListNode();
        head.data = obj;
    } else {
        newNode = head;
        while (newNode.link != null) {
            newNode = newNode.link;
        }
        // Now newNode.link is null
        // Creating the next node
        ListNode temp = new ListNode();
        temp.data = obj;
        // Assigning this new node to the last node's neighbor
        newNode.link = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to handle if `head` is `null` to begin with.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. Didn't think of that. I'll edit the post.

Comment: Thanks alot i think this answer is probably the best. Looking at it i see where i am going wrong. I need to point the last node to a node containing OBJ rather than pointing the null node to OBJ. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
if( head == null )
{
     //add to head
     ...
}
else
{
    //traverse the list
    for( Node tail = head;  tail.link != null;  tail = tail.link )
       ;

    //add to tail
    ...
}
```

Comment: newNode was the reference to the new code he created. If you do this way you lose reference to the new memory assigned to the new node. you should use a 2nd reference to point to heaqd

Comment: Whoops, you are right.  I will fix this for the sake of the 3 people who upvoted me!

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if its null and setting its data after that. It will give an NPE. When you reach the end do newNode.link = newNode

```
ListNode newNode = new ListNode();
newNode.data = obj;
if(head == null)
{ 
   head = newNode;
   return
}

ListNode curr = head;
while(curr.link!=null)
{
   curr=curr.link;
}
// curr now points to last node
curr.link = newNode
```

Comment: This doesn't handle the case when `head` is `null`.  @Dean Duff `curr = head`, not `newNode`.  newNode will be added on to the end of the list.

Comment: I was adding that. Plus his question was how to add at the end

Comment: Even when adding to the end you have to handle an empty list.  Adding to the end of an empty list means setting the head pointer to the new node.  Also the if statement you added will just set head to null every time.  You forgot an = sign.

Comment: what ar eyou atlking abt when you say Also the if statement you added will just set head to null every time. You forgot an = sign. . Its there

Comment: You wrote `if(head = null)` it needs to be `if(head == null)`.

Answer (score 0):

The condition would be the

```
while(newNode.link != null)
```

and initialize before putting into the data

```
newNode.link = new ListNode();
newNode.data = obj
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my answer i now have seems to be working as i want, every time i call an instance of addLast() it stores all current links and adds the OBJ data at the end of the list, the final code is:

```
public void addLast(int obj)
{
    ListNode newNode = new ListNode();
    newNode = head;
    while (newNode.link != null) 
    {
        newNode = newNode.link;
    }          

    ListNode last = new ListNode();
    last.data = obj;
    newNode.link = last; 

}
```

Thanks everyone!